# Can solve_ivp be interrupted?

Tags: scipy, numeric

Can scipy's solve_ivp be interrupted when during running a certain event happens, e.g. some expression changes from True to False?
Of course I want it to output the results achieved up to this point.
( I looked at this 'events(t, y)' possibility, but this seems to require a continuous function, which 'my' event is not.)

Thanks a lot for any help!!

Comment: Can you give some example code, including the function you're evaluating, and the event you want to terminate on? Is it good enough to know where the event happened, or is it also necessary to immediately terminate solve_ivp?